# How to deal with RxJava and Retrofit with many access to Realm ORM database and avoid Realm access from incorrect thread

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2, rx-java2

This question is often asked and resolved in many ways, but if I come back to the same question, it's because I'm a bit confused. This is my first time to deal with Realm ORM.

This repository class state for the implementation on db storage. Its take instance of Realm and ApiService

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl(var realm: Realm, var apiService: ApiService){
  override fun doLogin(email: String, password: String) {
     apiService.loginCheck(email, password)

            .flatMap { t: EntityToken ->

                // check if user already exist and delete it
                val checkIfUserExist = getUserIfExist("email", email)

                if (checkIfUserExist != null) {
                    realm.executeTransactionAsync {
                        checkIfUserExist.deleteFromRealm()
                    }

                }
                // insert user into DB
                realm.executeTransactionAsync { bgRealm ->
                    val user = bgRealm.createObject(UserModel::class.java, UserModel.cachedNextId)
                    user.email = email
                    user.logged = true
                }
                // i want to make another request to server
                return@flatMap apiService.pingServer(t.refresh_token)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ uR ->
                // make update of user table
                 realm.executeTransactionAsync {
                    getUserIfExist("email", email)?.fullname = uR.fullname
                 }
            }
     }

   //function to check if user instance already exist
    private fun getUserIfExist(field: String, email: String): UserModel? {
       return realm.where(UserModel::class.java)
            .equalTo(field, email)
            .findFirstAsync()
}
}
```

Ps.help me to resolve *Realm access from incorrect thread*

Answer (score 0):

You can create wrapper over realm that will use `Schedulers.single()`. It will use the same thread everytime. But I think I had to get Realm instance from that thread too.
I did it the ugly way

```
public long count() throws RealmException {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> realmService.getRealm().where(dataTypeClass).count())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .blockingGet();
}
```

realmService.getRealm() returns Realm instance that is lazily loaded only once.

You can also just return `Single` and chain calls using RxJava.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solve the problem by creating a new instance of Realm everytime i need to make a request.

I transformed my private function into this

```
 private fun getUserIfExist(db: Realm, email: String): UserModel? {
    return db.where(UserModel::class.java).equalTo("email", email).findFirst()
}
```

I created a new private function for the deleting

```
 private fun deleteInDb(db: Realm, email: String) {
    db.executeTransactionAsync {
        it.where(UserModel::class.java)
            .equalTo("email", email)
            .findFirst()
    }
}
```

To write into the table i created a private function too

```
 private fun writeToDB(entityToken: EntityToken, email: String): String? {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    realm.executeTransactionAsync { bgRealm ->
        var user = findInDb(bgRealm, email)
        if (user != null) {
            deleteInDb(bgRealm, email)
        }
        user = bgRealm.createObject(UserModel::class.java, UserModel.cachedNextId)
        user!!.email = email
        user.token = entityToken.token
        user.refreshToken = entityToken.refresh_token
        user.logged = true
    }
    realm.close()
    return entityToken.refresh_token
}
```

And finaly my doLogin function became

```
override fun doLogin(email: String, password: String) {
        apiService.loginCheck(email, password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map {
                // write to DB
                writeToDB(it, email, password)
                return@map it
            }
            .flatMap { ping ->
                //doPing to refresh token if not success
                if (!ping.success) {

                }
                return@flatMap apiService.userInfoFromServer
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ uR ->
                updateUserInfo(uR, email)

            }, { error ->
                Log.e("tt", error.message)

            })
    }
}
```

Its works but i got another problem. The fact that i am sending only Realm Object, so when i declared

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
```

It changing my RealmConfiguration 'database name' by 'default name'

Every solution is welcome!

Comment: the db name comes from RealmConfiguration.